# dropdown box on change event in SharePoint list forms

Tags: list, lookup-column, dropdown

I am editing an SharePoint list form using SharePoint Designer.  I need to have two drop down boxes one with the names of the countries and other with the names of appropriate state.  How can I achieve this using SharePoint Designer?

Since the state's column will have different state values for different countries, how do I set the column up?  What I mean is, country column can be a lookup field in another list which have all the country names in it.  How to setup the state column since it has to change for each select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with InfoPath, as it described here:

- [Cascading dropdown list in SharePoint 2010 using InfoPath 2010 article by Nguyen Ba Quang](http://msdnvietnam.net/blogs/quang/archive/2010/03/30/cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-infopath-2010.aspx)
- [Create cascading list box using InfoPath article on office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/create-a-cascading-list-box-HA001117713.aspx)

The other option is to use SPServices and its SPCascadeDropdowns functionality:

- [SPCascadeDropdowns documentation on CodePlex](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)